# $2n\choose n$ is divisible by all the primes between $10$ and $30$.

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

Find the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $2n \choose n$ is divisible by all the primes between $10$ and $30$.

Comment: Where did you get stuck on this problem?

Comment: This is turning out to be a much more difficult problem than I originally thought.  Attempting to brute force a solution by hand is becoming rather tedious (I have ruled out all n less than or equal to 50).  I'm halfway expecting now that this will be making it up triple digits or higher.

Comment: $n=11*13*17-1$ works

Comment: I know the answer is 44 and the solution is apparently simple (not computationally tedious at least), but I don't know what it is.

Comment: I don't know how to approach problems like this. I find it quite difficult at the moment.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=prime+factorization+of+binom%2888%2C44%29 is not divisible by 13, 19.  so, $n=44$ is incorrect.  I am looking into a proof involving Lucas' Theorem.  It seems to have the tools necessary for this.

Comment: It is not divisible by 11 either, which is the one I realized the fastest.

Comment: Also notice $27$ is not a prime

Comment: I can confirm that @TheEmperorofIceCream found a number which is infact divisible by all primes 10-30.  Now we either brute force check all $n$ from $30...2430$ to show it is smallest, or come up with a proof.

Comment: Sorry I meant 131 is the answer, not 44. I was confusing with a different problem.

Comment: Actually, I get $111$ as the answer.  Wrote it up in C++ calculating rows of Pascal's triangle mod $11(13)(17)(19)(23)(29)$.  The question now is how to get it without a program.

Comment: Interesting. The person who gave me this problem was wrong then. This is proving to be harder than I thought.

Comment: I feel we need to focus on Lucas's Theorem.

A binomial coefficient $\binom{m}{n}$ is divisible by a prime $p$ if and only if in base $p$ representation, at least one of the digits of $n$ is greater or equal to one of the digits of $m$.

I.e. for $m=m_kp^k + m_{k-1}p^{k-1}+\dots+m_1p + m_0$ and $n=n_kp^k + n_{k-1}p^{k-1}+\dots+n_1p + n_0$, you have that $\binom{m}{n} \equiv \prod_{i=0}^k \binom{m_i}{n_i}\mod p$

(using the convention where $\binom{a}{b}=0$ whenever $a<b$)

Comment: I always knew of this as a trivial corollary of Kummer's thoerem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Legendre's Criterion states that $v_p(n)=\dfrac{n-s_p(n)}{p-1}$ where $s_p(n)$ is the sum of the digits of $n$ written in base $p$.  Proving this is just algebra after you write out $n$ in base $p$.

Applying this, we see we simply need $2s_p(n)>s_p(2n)$ for all these primes.  If we don't get into squares of these primes, this means that $\lfloor \dfrac{2n}{p}\rfloor$ needs to be odd.  There doesn't seem to be a nice way to check this however, so we use brute force:

For $p=29$ we need $n\ge 15\ge 11$, so we need another power of $11$ on the top, giving $2n\ge 33\Rightarrow n\ge 17$.  This means we need another power of $17$ on the top, giving $2n\ge 51\Rightarrow n\ge 26$. Thus we need another power of $23$ (and $29$ of course) so we end up with $2n\ge 87\Rightarrow n\ge 44$.  Then we need another power of $11$ so we get $2n\ge 100\Rightarrow n\ge 50$, which unfortunately fails for $p=23$.

Darn.  Looks like we have to keep going.  Repeating this process we eventually get $2n\ge 222\Rightarrow n=111$, which works!  (I think...did this all by hand)

Note that the process gets marginally easier as we get larger since we get squares on the top for the smaller primes.  But it's still very bashy and I doubt there's a much better way to do this by hand.

Comment: Good method. How long did this take you? The problem is more tricky then I thought, and less elegant than I thought. There has got to be a better solution...

Comment: $111$ is indeed the first. A small `for` cycle in *Mathematica* confirms it.

Comment: It took me about 5 minutes after I figured out what to do...